# How to run multiple Scripts one by one in a powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have 8 scripts in Powershell which I run one by one. Let's call the scripts: `script1.bat, script2.bat, .., script8.bat`.

Now I need a script which runs all scripts.bat one by one, but not simultaneously.
And is there a way to check, if each script was successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./script1.bat
./script2.bat
./script3.bat
...
```

You'll get the picture, I guess. This will run them in sequence. To determine whether they were sucessful or not that depends very much on how those batch files signal errors or sucessful completion. If you exit with `exit /b 234` or something similar on an error then you can use `$LastExitCode` or also `$?` to determine that. You could also look whether the changes made by those batch files are actually done, of there is no other way of figuring out whether they were sucessful.