# Run Multiple Powershell Scripts Sequentially - on a Folder - Combine Scripts into a Master Script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have 6+ scripts and growing to run on a folder, what is the best way to have them run one after the other.

I have seen and tried this thread  - it did not work unfortunately.

[How to run multiple Scripts one by one in a powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966263/how-to-run-multiple-scripts-one-by-one-in-a-powershell-script)

In a  master .ps file  - I have put links to the power shell scripts that need to be run in order

## Run Scripts in order

```
'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Scripts\1.ps1'
'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Scripts\2.ps1'
'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Scripts\3.ps1'
```

etc

This did not work either. Your help is appreciated -  I have searched all over and can't seem to fix this issue.

**Revised:**  I believe I will have to wait for each power shell script to finish before running the  next one  - as I have had errors when I tried to run 3 scripts one after the other - nothing happened when the scripts were run

**Final**  -

I thank you all for your help - to keep things simple this is what I have done

My folder has the scripts below - I have then created a Master.ps1 with the code below inside it:

```
&"$PSScriptroot\1.ps1"
&"$PSScriptroot\2.ps1"
&"$PSScriptroot\3.ps1"
&"$PSScriptroot\4.ps1"
&"$PSScriptroot\5.ps1"
&"$PSScriptroot\6.ps1"
```

I have then run the Master.ps1  on the folder with all the files - and it does the job so far.

Comment: When you say `one after the other`, are you wanting to wait for each script to complete before running the next, or run them all at the same time?

Comment: Hi, I should wait for each one to finish - that makes sense. Run script 1 - then 2 then 3, sequentially :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to hard code the path, you can make Master.ps1 like this:

```
&"$PSScriptroot\1.ps1"
&"$PSScriptroot\2.ps1"
&"$PSScriptroot\3.ps1"
```

And it will look for those scripts in the same directory where it is.

Comment: Has `$PSScriptroot` always been there? I've been parsing the script root with `Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition` for what seems like forever.

Comment: Hi Mj -  I did this &"C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Mjolinor\1.ps1"

&"C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Mjolinor\2.ps1" -  it worked :)                            -  is there any chance - that it can wait to finish - before the next script runs - just in case in the future - I may have a long script , to prevent  spaghetti results in the text files - thank you

Comment: They will run sequentially by default.  You have to use jobs or runspaces to get it to multi-thread.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - $PSScriptRoot appears to have shown up in V3.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a text file, using any code editor or text editor, and use the following example batch script:

```
start /min powershell.exe C:\your folder\script1.ps1
start /min powershell.exe C:\your folder\script2.ps1
```

Save it as a `script.bat` and open it. This will make two powershell scripts run at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

To get the path that your script is in you can do this:

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

That will show something like 'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Scripts\Master.ps1'. From that we can do a `Split-Path` to get just the folder, and run `Get-ChildItem` on the folder to get a list of files. We'll probably want to exclude the master script, so that we don't end up in a recursive loop, so that would look something like:

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Get-ChildItem "$ScriptPath\*.ps1" | Where{$_.FullName -ne $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition}
```

Then we just run those through a `ForEach-Object` loop, and invoke the script with the call operator `&` as such:

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Get-ChildItem "$ScriptPath\*.ps1" | Where{$_.FullName -ne $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition} | ForEach-Object { & $_.FullName }
```

**Edit:** Hm, that wasn't filtering right. Here's a re-write that does filter out the master script correctly.

```
$Master = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Leaf
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Get-ChildItem "$ScriptPath\*.ps1" | Where{$_.Name -ne $Master} | ForEach-Object { & $_.FullName }
```

Comment: TMD, thank you - In the folder i put 2 scripts and the master script that calls those ...something happened .. but it went into a loop after.  In the master I put this :        $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Get-ChildItem "$ScriptPath\*.ps1" | Where{$_.FullName -ne $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition} | ForEach-Object { & $_.FullName }  - I am not sure if I did it right?

Comment: Sorry, my first version wasn't filtering out the master script, so it was running itself as part of the script, and that just created an endless loop. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you I will add this to my power shell tools - box - :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you hard coding the paths to the files in the master file?

In this case something like this should work

```
Invoke-Expression "C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Scripts\1.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Scripts\2.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Scripts\3.ps1"
```

Comment: I would prefer not to hard code - but as a powershell noob - I have no clue. If I put a master.ps in the folder with all the other scripts  - how would i call them from the master? Thank you Captain

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the powershell screen pops up is cuz you dont have the argument -NoExit set.  Please use the following as an example to see if your code is running properly:

```
Start-Process "$pshome\powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-NoExit", "-Command '& script'" -wait
```

Sorry for the late response but I also ran into the issue and thats how I was able to resolve it to make sure it was work.

Also I changes the file names as follows:

```
$Scripts =
@(
 ".\C:\Scripts\First.ps1"
 ".\C:\Scripts\Second.ps1"
 ".\C:\Scripts\Third.ps1"
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple scripts sequentially you can use the `-Wait` parameter on `Start-Process` like so:

```
$scriptsList = 
@(
    'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Scripts\1.ps1'
    'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Scripts\2.ps1'
    'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\Scripts\3.ps1'
)

foreach($script in $scriptsList)
{
    Start-Process -FilePath "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-command '& $script'" -Wait
}
```

PowerShell will wait for the current script to finish before running the next script

Comment: Hi BC - I ran this the power shell screens came up - but no changes happened in the text files - I don't know why :(