# Start multiple Selenium Nodes from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a running Selenium Hub, but I want to start a large number of Selenium Nodes to run off it. I'm trying to do so in PowerShell, but I don't really care what tool gets the job done.

The command to do so is

```
java `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\chromedriver.exe" `-jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar `-role node `-hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register `-browser "browserName=chrome,version=67,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
```

So I've tried

```
start "Title1" java `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\chromedriver.exe" `-jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar `-role node `-hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register `-browser "browserName=chrome,version=67,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
start "Title2" java `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\chromedriver.exe" `-jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar `-role node `-hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register `-browser "browserName=chrome,version=67,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
```

This just gives me this error without starting a node

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-jar'.
```

I suspect that part of the problem is all of the various quote marks in the command. I've also tried

```
$command = `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\chromedriver.exe" `-jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar `-role node `-hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register `-browser "browserName=chrome,version=67,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
start "Title1" java $command
start "Title2" java $command
```

along with a few other varients of that with different parts of the command as different variables.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Run Multiple Powershell Scripts Sequentially - on a Folder - Combine Scripts into a Master Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903038/run-multiple-powershell-scripts-sequentially-on-a-folder-combine-scripts-int)

Simply create a text file, using any code editor or text editor, and use the following example batch script:

```
start /min powershell.exe C:\your folder\script.ps1
start /min powershell.exe C:\your folder\script.ps1
```

Save it as a script.bat and open it. This will make two powershell scripts run at the same time.

The script itself just read

```
cd c:\
java `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\chromedriver.exe" `-jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar `-role node `-hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register `-browser "browserName=chrome,version=67,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
```